# Logging XML request in Java-WS invoke method

Tags: java, xml, web-services, logging

I'm using the Provider implementation of [java-ws](/questions/tagged/java-ws) and wish to log the XML request prior to attempting to work with it, preferably using [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j).

I've tried using `TransformerFactory` and `stdout` to log the incoming raw XML (below), which works, but when I do, the Source object can then no longer be used and generates NULL errors beyond the logging.

I'm assuming this is because it's a stream object and can only be used once.

```
private void printSource(Source source) {
    try {
        System.out.println("==========RESPONSE============");
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

        transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(System.out));
        System.out.println("\n==============================");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what container you're using. On WebSphere AS I just enable such logging in the trace settings. There may be something similar for your platform.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Apache Tomcat.  Thanks for the hint, it looks like Tomcat's "Access Log Valve" is what I'm after... I think.